# A loop for adding list element without high memory performance?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

Everybody,

```
a =[0, 0, 2, 4, 6]

x=5
```

This a list (`a`) and a fix value (`x`).

I need a loop codes which must add with x every element of list and add this value with previous list elements in every loop ( loop must continue as x value). Other words result should like below:

```
0
0
2
4
6
0
0
7
9
11
0
0
12
14
16
0
0
15
19
21
0
0
21
24
26
```

I prepared codes as below but it doesn’t work. Other words produce something as below (incorrect)

```
i=0
counter=0
while counter < x:
  for i in a:
     if i >0:
        i=i+x
    elif i ==0:
        i=0
    print i
  counter=counter+1
```

0
0
7
9
11
0
0
7
9
11
0
0
7
9
11
0
0
7
9
11
0
0
7
9
11

So, I need to help for this…
Thank you.

Comment: why dont you add it to the zeros?

Comment: because its a rule ( I forgotten the write above)

Comment: protip:  `counter = counter + 1` is equal to `counter += 1`; and `i = i + x` is equal to `i += x`

Comment: Should it be `...17, 19, 21...` instead of `...15, 19, 21...`

Comment: Unfortunately, index of elements can not change

Comment: Fix your example and add the missing rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does mostly what you want (at least, as I understand the question)...

```
def make_it_so(a, x):
  i = 0
  counter=0
  while counter < x:
    for i in a:
      if i == 0:
        yield 0
      else:
        yield i + counter * x
    counter = counter + 1

# Demo
for item in make_it_so([0, 0, 2, 4, 6], 5):
    print item
```

Note that I've made it a generator function.  You could easily turn it into a regular function that returns a list if you created an output list at the top of the function and swapped `yield ...` for `output_list.append(...)` and then `return output_list` at the end of the function...

The key here is to understand that in the first loop, you are adding `0` to all of the (non-zero) items.  In the second loop, you are adding `x`. In the third loop, you're adding the `x + x` (since the first loop added `x` and now you're adding `x` more).  In general, for the Nth loop, you'll be adding `(N-1) * x` to all of the non-zero items.  So, you just need to keep track of `N`, (or `N-1`).  In fact, your original code was already doing this (with `counter`), so we just re-purpose that and it's all good.

Comment: Tanks for your interesting and Helpful comment. This solition is wonderfull and ı will use it. Thanks again and again

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the values in `a`, not just add to the numbers you get out of `a` (because you'll keep getting the same ones out).  Also, you need to print out the original values.

Answer (score 0):

```
def process(x, memo):
    return [n+x if n else n for n in memo]

res = a
memo = a
for _ in range(x - 1):
    memo = process(x, memo)
    res.extend(memo)
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.